# Strategy for forgetting to run a script with `source`?

Tags: bash, scripting, source

I would like to write a script to access the state of an interactive bash shell, e.g. the script contains commands such as `jobs`, `dirs`, `pushd` and `popd`. So my strategy is to `source` the script in the shell when I run the script. 
But I often forget to `source` it and become  confused for a while depending on how soon I realize it.  Yes, I wrote the script myself.

So is there some best practice for forgetful people like me? For examples, is any of the following a good idea?

1. How can we make running the script  without typing `source`, for example, by modifying the script itself in some way?
2. How can we make the script itself remind me of `source` it? For example,

   - rename the script file with a prefix `Source_Me`?
   - Or is there some command used inside the script to detect whether the script is invoked by `source`, and if not, output error message?
3. Or should I try harder to remember which scripts need `source`?

   Thanks.

Comment: One fun way would be to `eval` a string that is the full content of the script. But no, just using `source` or `.` (dot) is the best (and only socially acceptable) way to execute another script file in the current shell's environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you source it, it doesn't require the execute bit.

Just don't make the script executable. If you then try to run it (without sourcing it), it just won't run (`Permission denied`), so no effect will happen. If it's in the PATH environment, a shell with completion (bash...) won't even try to autocomplete it with tab.

Now, you can just add in `.profile`, `.bashrc`  or similar an alias:

```
alias myscript='. /path/to/myscript'
```

So from now, on typing `myscript` will source it and run it as intended. The shell will even autocomplete the alias.

Comment: Nice trick. And if the script is on a filesystem that doesn't support Unix permissions then you can make it harmless with a shebang like `#!/bin/false`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of strategies you could use to print an error message if you run a script which is supposed to be sourced.

- You could check whether `$0` corresponds to your script’s name; if it does, it’s not being sourced, so print an error message an exit:

  ```
  if [ "${0##*/}" = "myscript" ]; then
      echo "Don't run me, source me" >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  ```

  (You would then need to take care to update that whenever your script is renamed...)

  A variant of this could be to  check `$0` against the contents of `/etc/shells`, if that’s an acceptable limitation (*i.e.* your shells scripts only ever run using shells listed there, which is by no means an obligation).
- If your script is only intended for use in an interactive shell, you could check for that — if it’s run instead of being sourced, it won’t be in an interactive shell:

  ```
  case "$-" in
  *i*) ;;
  *) echo "Don't run me, source me" >&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> How can we make the script itself remind me of `source` it?

Create a custom interpreter `source_reminder` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" "Source me!" >&2
exit 1
```

Then just use it in your executable script:

```
#!/path/to/your/source_reminder
foo
bar
whatever
```

Now if you run the script without sourcing, the reminder will do its job.

In my Debian `printf` itself may be used as a basic reminder:

```
#!/usr/bin/printf Source me! . %q\n
foo
bar
whatever
```

but naturally it prints to stdout when used this way and exits with success.

Answer (score 1):

seems you want a dot (.) like

```
#!/bin/sh
. includeMe.sh
```

but if you want just run all scripts from command like without any imperative "include"...

1. it is impossible, because when you type a command it executes by system() call (such syntax)
2. it is would be bad, because if in the script you run such way there is `exit` command it will bail out your current shell session

just try make script

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'bye world';
exit
```

and run it as `./script.sh` and compare with `. ./script.sh`

Comment: Dot is more or less the same as `source` in `bash`. If the issue is a problem with remembering to source a script, it will be the same with using dot.

Comment: I explained more. In fact I almost never need to run scripts from command line with source or dot. if you need kepp some vars, use `export` when set them, for push and pop, there is no way. can you make a sample when you using it ? May be there is much better way ?

Comment: also, if you not use `.` how you would to tell the interpreter about difference between includes and binary system commands ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a sourced script? Make it a function. So instead of

```
$ . something some args            # run it
```

have

```
$ cat define_something.sh
something() {
    commands here...
}
$ . define_something.sh            # load the function definition
$ something some args              # run the function
```

Or, if you want the actual commands to be in a sourced script, have a function to source it:

```
something() {
    . something "$@"
}
```

and then just run `something foo bar` instead of `. something foo bar`.

Of course functions hide the positional parameters of the main shell environment, so this won't work there. Perhaps an alias from `something` to `. something` if necessary. (Which was already suggested by [A.B in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442133/170373).)